# Error a llamar un function en jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hola amigos tengo el  siguiente codigo mi error es el siguiente:

**estoy haciendo un pequeño aplicacion en la cual cuando le das click a "dame click" cambiar de color eso funciona bien porque lo selecciono con Jquery pero cuando quiero agregar esa parte del codigo a una funcion para ser llamada atravez de un onclick no funciona, la otra parte del codigo que resetea el codigo al color original tampoco funciona si lo agrego a una funcion**

¿ ustedes que opinan ?

Mi codigo Actual :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function resetar() {
        $("#click").on('click', function () {
            $("#texto").css("color", "blue");
        });
    }
    
    resetar();

    //Resetear el color al original
    function resetar() {
        $("#click").on('click', function () {
            $("#texto").css("color", "black");
        });
    }
    
    resetar();
});
```

```css
.clase1 {
    color:red;
}
.clase2 {
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>App JQuery</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Introduccion a Jquery</h1>

    <p>Hi i'm Sommer0123</p>
    <p>Hi i'm Sommer0123</p>
    <p>Hi i'm Sommer0123</p>
    <p>Hi i'm Sommer0123</p>

    <p id="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
        aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <button id="click">Dame click</button>
    <button onclick="resetar()">Restaurar todo</button>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estas mezclando un poco los conceptos. Primero, las funciones se definen una sola vez. Segundo, los onclick no deberían ir dentro de una función (a menos que haya un motivo especifico para ello). Tercero, ten cuidado de definir una función y llamarla inmediatamente, puede causar cosas inesperadas.

Lo que tenes que hacer primero es definir que querés que hagan los botones:

```
<script>
$("#click").on('click', colorRojo);
$("#reset").on('click', colorAzul);

function colorRojo() {
  $("#texto").css("color","red");
}
function colorAzul() {
  $("#texto").css("color","blue");
}
</script>
```

html:

```
<button id="click">Dame click</button>
<button id="reset">Restaurar todo</button>
<button onclick="colorAzul()">Restaurar todo2</button>
```

Y por supuesto tenes varias formas de escribir las funciones

```
<button onclick="$('#texto').css('color','blue')">Restaurar todo3</button>
```

o en el js

```
$("#click").on('click', function(){$('#texto').css('color','red')});
$("#reset").on('click', function(){$('#texto').css('color','blue')});
```

etc

Comment: Gracias amigo  yo buscaba algo asi --> $("#click").on('click', colorRojo);
$("#reset").on('click', colorAzul);

function colorRojo() {
  $("#texto").css("color","red");
}
function colorAzul() {
  $("#texto").css("color","black");
}

Answer (score 1):

si estás usando *onclick* no debes poner $(#click).on("click") solo lo que quieres que cambie cuando se de click al botón, de esta manera:

```
function resetar(){
   $("#texto").css("color","blue");
}
```

Comment: Solo haciendo referencia así ID?

Comment: sí, no tiene sentido poner un onclick dentro de una función que se llama en un onclick

Answer (score 0):

Este es tu código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       function resetar(){
           $("#click").on('click',function(){
               $("#texto").css("color","blue");
           });
       }
   resetar();

   //Resetear el color al original

    function resetar(){
        $("#click").on('click',function(){
            $("#texto").css("color","black");
        });
    }
    resetar();
});
```

1. El botón que en teoría hace un reset de los colores está llamando a una función que se llama igual que otra función. Intenta ponerle nombres diferentes
2. Si ya usas on('click') no hace falta que lo pongas dentro de una función ya que eso ya es una función que te ejecutará el código de su interior al realizar una acción
3. Dentro del script llamas dos veces a la función resetear() y te dará problemas puesto que hay 2 que se llaman igual y por otra parte no tiene sentido llamarlas ahí.

Tendría que quedarte algo tal que así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#click").on('click',function(){ 
          $("#texto").css("color","blue");
      });    

      $("#btn-reset").on('click',function(){
          $("#texto").css("color","black");
      });
});

<button  id="click">Dame click</button>
<button id="reset">Restaurar todo</button>
```

O bien esto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      function colorAzul(){
          $("#texto").css("color","blue");
      }

       function colorNegro(){
          $("#texto").css("color","black");
      }
});

<button  onclick="colorAzul()">Dame click</button>
<button  onclick="colorNegro()">Restaurar todo</button>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me sirvio.